# Wordpress the REST API encountered an error with docker and docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem accessing `localhost:8000/wc-api/` on WordPress with Docker.

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
```

And I want to access WooCommerce API, on access the page I get 404 error.
[Screenshot of 404 error on access wc-api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3L4.png)

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbgS.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.